# Are Sharks able to detect electromagnetic waves using their Electroreception ability?

Tags: electrophysiology, senses

I will include some publications and links that may help. I could not concluded an answer with my limited knowledge on the subject.

[Shark Passive electroreception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroreception#Sensory_mechanism) sensitive to [low frequency (below 50 Hz).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency)

[Peer-reviewed Publications (Elasmobranch Research Laboratory).](http://www.science.fau.edu/sharklab/pages/publications.html)

Comment: Short answer yes sharks have an organ called the Ampullae of Lorenzini that allows them to sense electric fields given off by other animals. If you want to learn more check out this link http://www.sharksinfo.com/electroreception.html